# ADF jsff page F5 key

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

Any one knows how to capture F5 key from ADF jsff page? I believe javascript is the only way, and I know how to add clientlistener to a component to invoke javascript function, but can't figure out how to call javascript when F5 key is pressed, the document.keypress or document.keydown doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
document.onkeypress = keyHit; 
function keyHit(event) {
  // F5 or Ctrl+R
  if (event.keyCode == event.DOM_VK_F5 || 
      (event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey && (event.charCode == 114 || event.charCode == 82))
  ) 
  {

  event.stopPropagation(); 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  }
}
```